# Nested For loop performance optimization in JAVA

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

I was doing some coding challenges on HackerRank for a job application and although I am able to successfully complete all of the logic, I always fall behind in the performance aspect. Most of the time it has to do with a nested for-loop (I assume). This would run in O(n^2) time but I am assuming the challenge requires me to complete it faster than that.

Can anyone advise on how to increase performance? Below is an example code I have made. It passes the logic test cases but fails in performance time out.

```
 public static long maxValue(int n, List<List<Integer>> rounds) {
    
    int[] investments = new int[n+1];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rounds.size(); i++) {
        List<Integer> newList = rounds.get(i);
        for(int k = newList.get(0); k <= newList.get(1); k++) {
            System.out.println(k);
            investments[k] += newList.get(2);
        }
    }        
    
    int maxInt = Arrays.stream(investments).max().getAsInt();
    
    return maxInt;

}
```

I am a bit hesitant to post what the code is supposed to be doing in fear of people thinking this is homework, but here is the question:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You've missed out what the code is supposed to be doing?

Comment: For performance purposes, try to use dictionaries O(1) instead of lists O(n) as one takes considerably more time than the other during iteration.

Comment: @HarrisMinhas I am unable to change the parameters

Comment: The only thing that could possible be done is if you use a hashset instead of a list for the new variable investment that you are defining. For loop is the fastest in iteration as per <https://mkyong.com/java/while-loop-for-loop-and-iterator-performance-test-java/>

Comment: @HarrisMinhas advice is irrelevant for this problem. Their conclusion that nothing can be done is incorrect. I am crafting a proper answer now.

Comment: Can we assume you stripped out the `println` when you submitted it for scoring? (i*k occurrences)

Comment: The use of `List<List<Integer>>` instead of `List<Contribution>` leads me to believe this challenge was designed by a Lisp programmer.  It may be challenging, but it’s teaching a bad practice.

Comment: @Andy Yes definitely, I was using println for debugging purposes.

Comment: Definitely don't want printlns in what you submit for scoring as that counts against total execution time.

Answer (score -2):

When doing such problems, the 'easy way' (which, in this case, is clearly to make an int array such that each investment is one 'slot' in your array, and then just write some very basic loops) is rarely the right way, but the right way is usually [A] more complicated in the sense that there is more code and it is harder to follow, and [B] requires needing a small arsenal of 'tricks', from dynamic programming to many obscure math theorems, to rely on in order to even know what to do.

There are no easy answers as to how to gain this arsenal. Read a lot, learn a lot, do exercises like this for a few years. It's like becoming a world renowed crafter of tables: You just gotta craft a ton of tables, there are no shortcuts here.

There are 2 'easy' half-solutions, though (not that easy, but easier than spending a few years becoming an expert on this stuff):

- If you know a bit about fundamental informatics and NP-hard, that can help: If you get a feel that the algorithm you're envisioning could also be used to solve an NP-hard problem, guess what? Stop. It's wrong - it will be too slow. i.e. if it's 'as fast as' travelling salesman, knapsack, etcetera, then this is incorrect. This also helps when analysis problems itself: A ton of these exercises sound like one of the 8 well known NP-hard problems, just restated with a different story around it. That means you're looking for the key thing that makes it *not quite* like one of them, because the NP-hard set is too slow. Whatever part of the story doesn't quite match up vs the NP-hard problem you're comparing it to? That's the key to solving the problem in a performant way.
- Always look very carefully at the stated limits, which, it seems like, you forgot to include in your paste. Sometimes the limits give away a direction and often it is crucial to know about them to know which algorithm is the right answer.

With that as background, I have to know take a wild stab in the dark and guess that the 'limits' are something like:

The start index `s` and ending index `e` are such that `1 <= s < e <= 2000000000` (that's 2 billion). The amount of rounds `n`: `1 <= n <= 100000`, and finally, the total amount invested is guaranteed to be positive numbers and the answer will never be more than 2 billion.

If a problem does not contain such a block of limits, I'd wager a guess that the materials you're working from are badly designed. Find other material. The vast majority of puzzles like this are not solvable without knowing such constraints or require guessing, and surely you wouldn't want to play a game where the winner just got lucky. You want to play a game where the winner is the one that has the most skill.

*IF* the limits are as I described, then imagine the following input data set:

```
amount start end
10     1     1000000000
10     1     1000000000
10     1     1000000000
10     1     1000000000
10     1     1000000000
```

Your algorithm would loop 6 billion times in order to determine the correct answer. Surely, just thinking about it right now, you already realized that with such inputs, an algorithm that loops more on the order of 6 times (a speed increase of a billion, literally) is possible as well.

Therein lies the rub. Once you break it down into single investments you've already lost the game. Instead you want to embrace those ranges.

There are custom data types in e.g. guava that let you work with ranges. You could also write this code yourself.

An easy algorithm is to have a data structure that maps **disjoint** ranges onto the right sum. Thus, if the inputs are:

```
amount start end
10     1     1000
20     1     500
30     1     1000
```

then after processing the first round your data structure contains only 1 entry and not 1000 entries. That one entry is:

```
1-1000    10
```

During the processing of the second input you realize that you have to split it up. You end up with 2 entries (not 1000):

```
1-500     30
501-1000  10
```

after the third:

```
1-500     60
501-1000  40
```

You can also track the maximum as you run (just update 'max' every time you add anything to anything - no need to loop at the end, but I doubt that's the reason your algorithm is considered too slow here. That one final loop over all your data structures doesn't change your `O(n)` rating).

**IF** (big if!) the input ranges are such that the start/end index can be very large, this will be an algorithm that will likely pass the performance limits.

There are more convoluted strategies with overlapping ranges; this involves first sorting your inputs. This is more likely to be correct if the input size can be very large (a ton of rounds) and the start/index limits are restricted.